# Can i programatically get the link backs from Facebook to my web-page?

Tags: facebook, web

I want to fetch the link backs from facebook to my web-site. Basically I want to fetch how many users have come to my web-site from the like/shared link posted over facebook for my web-site. Can i fetch these values using any of the FB API??

Answer (score 0):

FB API doesn't have that ability.  Here's what you do.  On your website check the HTTP_REFERER attribute of each web request.  When the referrer is Facebook, track it.  Then you can know the counts.  If you cannot do that, then you can use something like Google Analytics to do the tracking and reporting.